# It is possible to access vendor files from within a view in Symfony >= 2.0?

Tags: symfony-2.1

I have installed Twitter Bootstrap Framework as a vendor in Symfony 2.1 using composer package manager as a package from github repo. My intention is to "include" some files of this vendor inside of the *::base.html.twig* layout directly, without having to create a Bundle to handle this.

How I can access files of a vendor like *"vendor/twitter/bootstrap"* from within a view ?

Comment: What do the quotes around include mean exactly? Do you really want to have the contents of thes files included in your template? Or do you simply wish to link to a css stylesheet?

Comment: There is some readymade Bundle about twitter bootstrap integration: [mopa/bootstrap-bundle](http://packagist.org/packages/mopa/bootstrap-bundle), [ruian/TwitterBootstrapBundle](https://github.com/ruian/TwitterBootstrapBundle) [polmabri/twitter-bootstrap-bundle](http://packagist.org/packages/polmabri/twitter-bootstrap-bundle)... Why not using one of them?

Comment: why use a bundle to wrap it when all you need are the css  or less files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh sorry, i've found my own question when searching on google. I Lost the contents of the form the day I was trying to publish this question while submitting xD And thought it wasn't published, and today, surprise LOL.

Ty for all the answers, fortunately found the solution by myself. If my experience can help anyone... Since 2.1 version is posible to get the twitter bootstrap package from github and install it as a vendor using composer.phar

In the composer.json file at the root of the project add this to the "require": {} section:

```
"twitter/bootstrap": "dev-master",
```

Then at the "repositories": {} section add:

```
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "version": "master",
            "name": "twitter/bootstrap",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            },
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/master",
                "type": "zip"
             }
        }
    },
```

Then with node.js for windows installed u can execute:

```
npm install -g less jshint recess uglify-js
```

and

```
make
```

To compile again the docs subfolder that contains the compiled library or...

```
make bootstrap
```

That compiles the css, js, minified versions too in a bootstrap subfolder

Then, is possible to call and make use of bootstrap this way:

```
{% stylesheets '../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}

{% javascripts '../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

**The advantage** of this approach is that is possible to update the version of the vendor by simply using:

```
cd /path/to/symfony/root/dir
php composer.phar update Twitter/Bootstrap
```

And compile again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use assetics css rewrite to do what you are asking:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite' output='css/frontend.css'
   '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/path/to/stylesheet.css'
%}
```

[**edit:** see here for a recent googlegroups discussion on [the topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/symfony2/lY627yx_ncc) ]